# How to get paypal app id to use adaptive payments paypal?

Tags: paypal

How to get paypal app id to use adaptive payments paypal ?

i want to use adaptive payments paypal in my website but i not have paypal app id.

i search on internet , they tell access to x.com , but when i access to x.com . it's will direct to ebayinc.com

When i access to ebayinc.com , i cannot fine menu "Create App"

How can i do ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following page outlines the process for going live with adaptive payments: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register